# How can I run servlet-filter of a different project in my project without spring @Component or @Bean annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, servlet-filters

I am working with a usecase where there is a project containing servlet-filter acting as a middleware. To run this filter, i am putting `@Component` on the servlet-filter class. And in my another application i put the package containing this filter like below.

Project A (which acts as a middleware)

```java
package com.filter_demo;
.
.
.

@Component
public class middleware extends HttpFilter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
   System.out.println("Inside init of filter");
}

@Override
public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain){

System.out.println("incoming request");

filterChain.doFilter(request,response);

System.out.println("outgoing response");
}

@Override
public void destroy(){

}
}
```

Project B (containing actual application logic, controller etc)

```java
package com.demoApp;
.
.
.
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.demoApp","com.filter_demo"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

***Note: If i don't put @Component on the filter class then the http request doesn't come to this filter.***

How can i use this filter without adding @Component on it, basically making it independent of spring so that i can use this filter in my core-java non-springboot application which uses servlets, jsp, etc.

And i don't want to make major changes in the Project B ( my application ) to register that filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace `@Component` annotation from "Middleware"/filter, this is sufficient/equivalent:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.demoApp","com.filter_demo"})// or any "visible configuration"
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean // !
    public middleware middleware(/*...*/) {
       return new middleware(/*...*/);
    }
}
```

...to make the filter "spring independent", you should also ensure, that it uses no other `[import] org.springfr...*`.

In your target (non-spring) e.g. web.xml application, you would configure it like:

```xml
<filter> 
    <filter-name>myMiddleware</filter-name> 
       <filter-class>com.filter_demo.middleware</filter-class> 
      <!-- init-param>
        <param-name>foo</param-name>
        <param-value>bar</param-value>
      </init-param-->
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping> 
       <filter-name>myMiddleware</filter-name> 
       <url-pattern>/foo/bar/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
</filter>
```

Comment: Flow is going to the Filter. Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 2):

The minimal change that you require to make in project B is to manually and explicitly define this filter using `@Import` instead of relying using component scan for finding the spring bean based on `@Component` :

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.demoApp","com.filter_demo"})
@Import({middleware.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: To make the Project A independent of spring, and use this filter inside a spring boot application, this import statement is working absolutely fine. Thanks for that!...Can we also mention a package of a multimodule project here. for eg: suppose Project A is a multi module project having different servlet-filters in each module. and I want to write only package name not every filter class of each module.

Comment: I guess you need to implement a `ImportSelector` in this case  and then use `@Import` with this `ImportSelector`. The `ImportSelector` mainly will then use reflection to find out and return all the existence Filter class in a packages.

Comment: sure, will try this one.